# Passing a Date instance to Date constructor to clone Dates

Tags: javascript, date

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date), we can pass only the following types of parameters to `Date` constructor:

```
new Date();
new Date(value); // Unix timestamp
new Date(dateString);
new Date(year, monthIndex [, day [, hours [, minutes [, seconds [, milliseconds]]]]]);
```

So technically, we can't pass another `Date` instance to the `Date` constructor.

However, the following works fine in Firefox and Chrome:

```
new Date(new Date(1990, 1, 1));
```

Why does it work? Is this a correct way to clone `Date` objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [ECMAScript specification](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/index.html#sec-date-value), 9th edition (from June 2018)

> If `Type(value)` is `Object` and `value` has a `[[DateValue]]` internal slot,
>   then Let `tv` be `thisTimeValue(value)`.

So the behavior you observe is a standard (not some experimentation), and should be implemented by all modern browsers.

Comment: Thank you! Are you aware of any info on the actual progress of implementing this one across browsers (maybe caniuse.com or something)?

Comment: Until ECMAScript 2015 (ed 6), implementations were required to convert the date to a string using their implementation dependent *toString*, then parse that (why? no idea). The result was that IE did not correctly parse its own dates outside of the 20th century (IE's date string used 2 digit years and parsed them all to 19xx), so a safe way to copy a date was `new Date(+date)` to use the time value instead. Y2K issues lingered long after 2000. ;-)

Comment: @AlexanderAbakumov I don't know where you can find this information, except on every browser editor's website

Comment: Thank you! And the last question, please. Is it indeed the new recommended way to clone dates now for browsers supporting `new Date(date);`? So, can we now stop doing `new Date(date.getTime())`.

Comment: Well this is now in the standard to get rid of the previous techniques, each one hackier than the last (plus sign to convert to number, etc...) so the only reason why you wouldn't use it is for backwards compatibility